# Does Template 10 implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: mvvm, template10

Does the Visual Studio project template known as Template 10 implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Or does it leave that to whatever MVVM toolkit like MVVM Light or PRISM to define that? (Or of course one could roll their own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Template 10, the `ViewModelBase` implements the `BindableBase`, and the `BindableBase` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You can extend the `ViewModelBase` in your view model, and use the `Set(ref _Value, value)` method to invoke `PropertyChanged` event.